# Glossaries package and acronyms with an &

Tags: glossaries

I'm using glossaries package and have one entry that has an & in between:

```
%\newacronym{CK}{CK}{Chidamber \& Kemerer}
\newglossaryentry{CK}{type =\acronymtype,
                      name={CK},
                      description={Chidamber \& Kemerer},
                      text={CK},
                      first={Chidamber \& Kemerer (CK)},
                      plural={CKs},
                      firstplural={Chidamber \& Kemerers (CKs)}}
```

in both variants I do get an " in front of the and char and it looks like this:

```
Chidamber "& Kemerer
```

whenever I use \glsdesc{CK}

Does someone see a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the glossaries manual:

> Note: if you want to use this command and the
>   description key contains commands, you will have to disable the sanitization of
>   the description key and protect fragile commands.

See for further information: http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf